# how scan part of rows in hbase from eclipse

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I have a big table in hbase that name is Hweather. this table have some columnfamily like this:
Hweather(Province,City,Station,instant).

This column families have own column qualifiers.
so I want select or means scan two column (Date,temperature) when the columnfamily is Instant and when the rowkey prefix is 16,20,.. and then stop scan operation when prefix rowkey is 17,20.

it means start row is 16,20,...
and stop row is 17,20,...

so I try do this in java. but I did nit get any answered.can you help me to correct this and do this operation?

the code is like bellow :

```
package scan;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultScanner;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.Filter;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.PrefixFilter;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;

 public class scan2 {

public static void main(String args[]) throws NoClassDefFoundError, IOException {

    Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
            config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost");
            HTable table = new HTable(config, "Hweather");

    Filter colfilter=new PrefixFilter(Bytes.toBytes("Date"));
    Filter colfilter1=new PrefixFilter(Bytes.toBytes("Temperature"));
   Scan scan1 = new Scan(Bytes.toBytes("16,20,100,1"),(Bytes.toBytes("17,20,100,1")));
    Scan scan2 = new Scan(Bytes.toBytes("16,20,100,1"),(Bytes.toBytes("17,20,100,1")));
    scan1.setFilter(colfilter1);
    scan2.setFilter(colfilter2);
    ResultScanner scanner1= table.getScanner(scan1);
    ResultScanner scanner2= table.getScanner(scan2);

  for (Result result1= scanner1.next(); result1 !=null; result1= scanner1.next()) {
      for (Result result2= scanner2.next(); result2 !=null; result2= scanner2.next()) { 
        System.out.println("scanner1" + "scanner2"); 
      }

    }
  }

 }
```

it does not work and just show me :

```
 2013-11-10 16:20:20,959 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper    
 (Environment.java:logEnv(100)) - Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.5-1392090,  
 built on 09/30/2012 17:52 GMT
 2013-11-10 16:20:20,963 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper (Envi
  ronment.java:logEnv(100)) - Client environment:host.name=localhost
 2013-11-10 16:20:20,963 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper 
 (Environment.java:logEnv(100)) - Client environment:java.version=1.6.0_27
 2013-11-10 16:20:20,964 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper 
 (Environment.java:logEnv(100)) - Client environment:java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
 2013-11-10 16:20:20,964 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper  
 (Environment.java:logEnv(100)) - Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-
 6-openjdk-i386/jre
  2013-11-10 16:20:20,969 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper   
 (Environment.java:logEnv(100)) - Client environment:java.class.path=/home/ubuntu 
 /workspace/Scan/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.0.2-alpha.jar:
 /usr/local/hadoop/lib/hbase-protocol-0.95.0-hadoop2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/hadoop-  
 fairscheduler-1.0.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/hadoop-minicluster-2.0.2-alpha.jar:
 /usr/local/hadoop/lib/hadoop-yarn-api-2.0.2-alpha.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/hadoop-   
 mapreduce-client-app-2.0.2-alpha.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/hadoop-auth-2.0.2-alpha.jar:
 /usr/local/hadoop/lib/hadoop-yarn-common-2.0.2-alpha.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/hadoop-
 mapreduce-client-common-2.0.2-alpha.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/hbase-common-0.95.0-
 hadoop2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/hbase-it-0.95.0-hadoop2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop
 /lib/hbase-client-0.95.0-hadoop2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/hadoop-hdfs-2.0.2-alpha.jar:
 /usr/local/hadoop/lib/hadoop-thriftfs-1.0.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/hbase-hadoop-c
 ompat-0.95.0-hadoop2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.0.2-
 alpha.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.0.2-alpha.jar:/usr/local
 /hadoop/lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.0.2-alpha.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/hadoop-
 mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.0.2-alpha.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/hadoop-yarn-server-
 nodemanager-2.0.2-alpha.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.0.2-alpha.jar:
 /usr/local/hadoop/lib/hadoop-common-2.0.2-alpha.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/hadoop-
 yarn-client-2.0.2-alpha.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/hbase-server-0.95.0-hadoop2.jar:
 /usr/local/hadoop/lib/hadoop-capacity-scheduler-1.0.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/hadoop-
 mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.0.2-alpha.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/hadoop-client-2.0.2-
 alpha.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/hbase-prefix-tree-0.95.0-hadoop2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop
 /lib/hbase-hadoop2-compat-0.95.0-hadoop2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/hadoop-yarn-server-
 resourcemanager-2.0.2-alpha.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/hbase-0.20.0.jar:/usr/local
 /hadoop/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/local
 /hadoop/lib/asm-3.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop
.........
 2013-11-10 16:20:20,970 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper    
 (Environment.java:logEnv(100)) - Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
 2013-11-10 16:20:20,971 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper 
 (Environment.java:logEnv(100)) - Client environment:os.name=Linux

 2013-11-10 16:20:20,971 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper 
 (Environment.java:logEnv(100)) - Client environment:os.arch=i386
 2013-11-10 16:20:20,972 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper 
 (Environment.java:logEnv(100)) - Client environment:os.version=3.2.0-23-generic-pae
 2013-11-10 16:20:20,972 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper 
 (Environment.java:logEnv(100)) - Client environment:user.name=ubuntu
 2013-11-10 16:20:20,972 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper 
 (Environment.java:logEnv(100)) - Client environment:user.home=/home/ubuntu
 2013-11-10 16:20:20,973 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper 
 (Environment.java:logEnv(100)) - Client environment:user.dir=/home/ubuntu/workspace
 /Scan

 2013-11-10 16:20:20,974 INFO  [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeper (ZooKeeper.java:<init>(438)) -
  Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000    
 watcher=hconnection-0x16546ef
 2013-11-10 16:20:21,002 INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn 
 (ClientCnxn.java:logStartConnect(966)) - Opening socket connection to server  
 localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
 2013-11-10 16:20:21,004 INFO  [main] zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper 
 (RecoverableZooKeeper.java:<init>(119)) - The identifier of this process is 
  hconnection-0x16546ef
 2013-11-10 16:20:21,017 INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn 
 (ClientCnxn.java:primeConnection(849)) - Socket connection established to 
 localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
 2013-11-10 16:20:21,038 INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn 
 (ClientCnxn.java:onConnected(1207)) - Session establishment complete on server 
 localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x14241e6ac200005, negotiated timeout = 40000
 2013-11-10 16:20:21,116 INFO  [main] 
 client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation 
 (HConnectionManager.java:retrieveClusterId(680)) - ClusterId is f6e88331-aea1-4bd3-
  a579-f4a22524d9cf
 2013-11-10 16:20:21,385 WARN  [main] conf.Configuration 
  (Configuration.java:warnOnceIfDeprecated(816)) - hadoop.native.lib is deprecated.   
  Instead, use io.native.lib.available
```

and do not give me any out put.can you guide me how correct it.or how I can do this?

thanks

Comment: use Scan#addColumn instead of filters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it helps :

```
public class PrefixFilterDemo {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


            Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();    
            HTable table = new HTable(conf, "Hweather");    
            Scan s = new Scan();    
            s.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("Instant"), Bytes.toBytes("Date"));    
            s.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("Instant"), Bytes.toBytes("Temprature"));
            Filter f = new PrefixFilter(Bytes.toBytes("16,20"));    
            s.setFilter(f);    
            ResultScanner rs = table.getScanner(s);    
            for(Result r : rs){    
                  System.out.println("ROW : " + Bytes.toString(r.getRow()));        
            }    
            rs.close();    
            table.close();    
      }

}
```